# 'Vertical Box' : Box Vbox = new Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 6); doesn't go through dotnet run ( 6.0/GTK 3.24.24/VStudioC/linux)

Tags: c#, gtk#

in order to get a listView, I use the old `VBox vbox = new VBox(false,6);` instead of `Box vbox = new Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 6);`

when using `Box vbox = new Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 6);`

dotnet run (dotnet 6, Gtk# 3.24.24 on visual studio code) replies by :

```
error CS0117: 'Orientation' doesn't contain any definition for 'VERTICAL'
```

need a little help to switch to the newer version of vertical box method.

I put in a Vbox class : didn't work because maybe I coded it the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help

I've coded `Box vbox = new Box(Orientation.Vertical, 0);`

and it works fine